# Netsuite Suitescript: How to retrieve records based on last modified date?

Tags: search, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to retrieve records in Netsuite via SuiteScript. I would like to use the `lastmodifieddate` column to fetch record after a certain timestamp.

I am currently doing:

```
var filters = [new nlobjSearchFilter('lastmodifieddate', null, 'notbefore', time)];
var columns = [new nlobjSearchColumn('lastmodifieddate')];
var newSearch = nlapiCreateSearch(table, filters, columns);
var searchResultSet = newSearch.runSearch();
var back = nextEndIndex - 1000
var results = searchResultSet.getResults(back, nextEndIndex);
```

Where `time` is a datetime JS, `nextEndIndex` index counter for results.

This works for some objects but majority of Netsuite objects do not have the `lastmodifieddate` column in the record browser. Is there a built in variable for the `lastmodifieddate`? And if there is, how can I use it in `nlapiCreateSearch`? If you have better ways to do it, I would be grateful for the info.

Comment: I noticed that `date_last_modified` is present in Connect Browser but it is highlighted in red.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example for SuiteScript 2.0.

```
define(['N/search'],function(search){
  function test(chkDate){
    log.debug(chkDate);
    var empSearch=search.create({
      type:search.Type.EMPLOYEE,
      columns:['internalid','firstname','lastmodifieddate'],
      filters:['lastmodifieddate','after',chkDate]
    }).run().each(function(result){
      log.debug(JSON.stringify(result));
      return true;
    });
  }
  test('05/30/2017');
});
```

This example is searching for employees, since I was not sure which record type you were looking at.  Below are links to the information you can use to build out your searches:

1. [Records Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_2/script/record/account.html) (look at the bottom of each section in the filters and columns):
2. [Search Operators](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n3005172.html) (shows which ones to use for which field types)
3. [API Docs](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.)

Comment: That is another good way to do it. But majority of the records do not have the `lastmodifieddate` column in the Records Browser. There is a `date_last_modified` column but it is only available in the Connect Browser (reserved for ODBC connections). Is there a way to search objects without the `lastmodifieddate` for their last modification timestamp?

Comment: I see lastmodifieddate on every standard record, and I use it regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are slightly different than entities. Transactions have lines. If you are trying to determine the true last modified date of a transaction, you may need to consider using the "Line Last Modified" field in place of "Last Modified Date." Try writing a simple search to pull Sales orders. Include "Last Modified Date" and "Line Last Modified." Then write a simple formula to show those that don't match. When I did this, there were a number of mismatches, with instances of "Line Last Modified" being more than 1 month later than "Last Modified Date." So if you are looking for the true last modified date, you may need to use the max "Line Last Modified."

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 'Max' Summary Filter on `{systemnotes.date}` - you will of course need to Group by record (document number or internal id for example) for this to show correct results.